# Get checkboxes checked/unchecked value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.IsAnonymous)
<input type="checkbox" id="cbIsAnonymous" name="MyCheckbox"/>
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.ShowReport)
<input type="checkbox" id="cbShowReport" name="MyCheckbox"/>
```

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Is Anonymous")]
public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }    
[Display(Name = "Show Report")]
public bool ShowReport { get; set; }
```

**Home Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Publish(string[] MyCheckbox)
{
   return View();
}
```

I don't know how to get whether checkboxes checked/unchecked value to home controller from view. Searched few pages and I built this piece of code in controller. But when I applied debugger to this method I found that I'm not getting value from view to my controller.

Comment: Generate you checkboxes correctly - `@Html.CheckboxFor(p => p.IsAnonymous)` and `@Html.CheckboxFor(p => p.ShowReport)` - ALWAYS use the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate form controls. And you POST method need to be `public ActionResult Publish(yourModel model)`

Comment: You should use this: `public ActionResult Publish([Bind(Include = MyCheckbox)] ModelName model)`. But it's better to use `CheckBoxFor` with strongly-typed viewmodel.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  - the `BindAttribute` would be pointless (the model does not contain a property named `MyCheckbox`)

Comment: friend! as you know you must use name binding. For example , so change this  `name="IsAnonymous"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strongly typed model and your view look like below with strongly typed model ,
  check boxes with different names

```
    @model Model   

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Publish", "Home",                
            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" },
            new { id = "form1" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.IsAnonymous)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.IsAnonymous);
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.ShowReport)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.ShowReport});
    }
```

controller  action  takes model as parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Publish(ModelName model)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Fortunately `name="MyCheckbox1"` does absolutely nothing at all (if it did, model binding would not work), and the `id="cbIsAnonymous"` is pointless

Comment: @user9405863 did as u told. But debugger's control not going to **ActionResult** block. I wanna check whether checked values coming or not.

Comment: @akshaysahu i showed example. pls replace Model with your model name in view and ModelName with your model name in action respectively.also i added ajax options(POST) in the answer. use the updated answer .

Comment: @user9405863 it would be a great help if u would tell me that how can I write this value to my table in database. I Have a column name **IsAnonymous** and **ShowReport**. Thanks

Comment: Ru using ORM or ado.net? There will be plenty of samples on how to use entity framework or ado.net

Comment: MVC @user9405863

Comment: @akshayalong with MVC which technology you are using for data access?